# How to setup karma config in Node js + Jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine, code-coverage

I am using express for nodeJS. I have written unit test case using jasmine framework. How to generate the code coverage report using karma with Istanbul reporter.

Answer (score 1):

If your codebase is node, so you can simply [run jasmine as your test runner](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html):

```
jasmine src/**/*.spec.js
```

now just add istanbul:

```
istanbul cover jasmine src/**/*.spec.js
```

a simple configuration for istanbul should be in `.istanbul.yml`:

```
instrumentation:
    excludes: [
      "**/*.spec.js"
    ]
reporting:
  reports:
    - lcov
    - json-summary
    - html
check:
  global:
    statements: 95
    branches: 95
    functions: 95
    lines: 95
```

Comment: Thanks..Node libraries(request, kafka-node) are not supported in Istanbul code coverage in Node JS.How to solve this?